# Limit of sequences involving the $n$-th root

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Consider a sequence $u_n$ of positive terms. In order to compute the limit of $\sqrt[n]{u_n}$, I know that if $$\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\rightarrow a,$$ then also $\sqrt[n]{u_n}\rightarrow a$. Is this still true if $a=+\infty$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. See for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/335531/147873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Fix $M>0$. If $u_{n+1}/u_n\to\infty$, then there exists $n_0$ such that $u_{n+1}>M\,u_n$ for all $n>n_0$. Thus
$$
u_{n_0+k}>M^k u_{n_0},
$$
and then $$\sqrt[n_0+k]{u_{n_0+k}}>M^{k/(n_0+k)}\,u_{n_0}^{1/(n_0+k)}.
$$
Taking $k\to\infty$, we get
$$
\sqrt[n_0+k]{u_{n_0+k}}>M.
$$
As we can do this for each $M>0$, we get that $\sqrt[n]{u_n}\to\infty$.

Comment: great! thank you very much!