# How to rigorously find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n \colon= \sqrt[n]{n!} $
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then how to determine rigorously whether the sequence $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ converges or diverges?

And, how to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, rigorously?

By *rigorously* I mean using the same machinery as has been developed by Rudin until Chap. 3, where he discusses sequences.

My Attempt:

> We note that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > 1$, we have
>   $$ 1 \leq \left( x_n \right)^n \leq n^{n-1}, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ 1 \leq x_n \leq n^{ (n-1)/n } = \frac{ n }{\sqrt[n]{n} }. $$
>   However, although 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1, $$
>   we also have 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n = +\infty. $$
>   Thus the squeeze theorem is not applicable.

Or, can we find some majorizing sequence converging to $1$?

Is this sequence monotonic?

Comment: Find the limit of $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}/\sqrt[n]{n!}$. That, if you don't want to just invoke Stirling's formula.

Comment: By the elementary inequality $n!\geq\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, such limit is clearly $+\infty$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the series $\sum \dfrac{1}{n!}$ and use the root test.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive it form [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):$$\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac12}e^{-n}\leqslant n!\leqslant en^{n+\frac12}e^{-n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By [ratio-root criteria](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335500/do-the-sequences-from-the-ratio-and-root-tests-converge-to-the-same-limit)

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{n!} \quad b_n=n!$$

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \rightarrow L\implies a_n=b_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow L$$

thus since

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{{(n+1)!}}{n!}=n+1\to+\infty \implies a_n = \sqrt[n]{n!}\to +\infty $$

Answer (score 1):

Taking log plus Cesàro-Stolz:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\sqrt[n]{n!} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log 1 + \cdots + \log n}n =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n = \infty,
$$
so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From

$$(2n-k)(n-k)\gt(2n-2k)(n-k)=2(n-k)^2$$

for $0\lt k\lt n$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x_{2n}
&=\sqrt[2n]{(2n)!}\\&=\sqrt[2n]{(2n)(n)(2n-1)(n-1)\cdots(n+2)(2)(n+1)(1)}\\
&\gt\sqrt[2n]{2(n)^22(n-1)^2\cdots2(2)^22(1)^2}\\
&=\sqrt2\sqrt[n]{n!}
\end{align}$$

for $n\ge2$. (The inequality is not strict for $n=1$, because there are no $k$'s between $0$ and $1$.) Thus the sequence has subsequences, at least, that diverge to infinity, for example

$$x_{2^{n+1}}\gt(\sqrt2)^n\to\infty$$

To show that the sequence as a whole diverges to infinity, it suffices to show that $x_{n+1}\gt x_n$, i.e.,

$$((n+1)!)^n\gt(n!)^{n+1}$$

which is to say,

$$(n+1)^n\gt n!$$

which is obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

By elementary means:

Consider the sequence

$$2^0,2^1,2^1,2^2,2^2,2^2,2^2,2^3,2^3,2^3,2^3,2^3,2^3,2^3,2^3,\cdots2^b,2^b,2^b,\cdots 2^b$$

term-wise inferior to the naturals.

We obviously have

$$n!\ge 2^{b2^b}=2^{b(n+1)/2}$$

hence the series diverges.