Prove that the sequence $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ diverges to infinity
Currently, I have that $\sqrt n \leq \sqrt[n]{n!}$ for all integers $n≥1$, and since the sequence in the lower bound $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n=\infty $ blows up, so does the upper bound $x_n=\sqrt[n]{n!}$
This feels quite hand-wavey and unsatisfying to me, so I was curious if there any other creative / more formal ways to prove its divergence?

$\lim_n \sqrt[n]{n!} = \lim_n \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = \lim_n (n+1) = \infty$, for example

Note that if $a_n$ is any sequence of positive numbers then $$\liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

@Jakobian This inequality is really useful in various problems... Your comment needs to be an answer :)

If you have actually shown $\sqrt n \leq \sqrt[n]{n!}$, there is nothing less hand-wavy than observing that the lower bound goes to $+\infty$. Do you have doubts about the part you haven't shown us?

@Nothingspecial This question is a very common duplicate, and its not very interesting to me.

@Jakobian Right... This has been popularly asked at least twice :)

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2701743/589

This is an immediate consequence of the exponential series $\sum x^n/n!$ having infinite radius of convergence.
The radius of convergence $R$ of a real power series $\sum a_nx^n$ can be described by $1/R = \varlimsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. Taking $a_n = 1/n!$, so $R = \infty$ thanks to $e^x$ having an infinite radius of convergence, $0 = \varlimsup \sqrt[n]{1/n!} = \varlimsup 1/\sqrt[n]{n!}$.  When a sequence of nonnegative numbers has $\varlimsup$ equal to $0$, the sequence tends to $0$, so $1/\sqrt[n]{n!} \to 0^+$.  Thus $\sqrt[n]{n!} \to \infty$.
Alternatively, since $e^n = \sum_{k \geq 0} n^k/k!$, looking at the $n$-th term on the right shows $e^n > n^n/n!$ when $n \geq 1$, so $n! > n^n/e^n$. Now take $n$th roots: $\sqrt[n]{n!} > n/e$ when $n \geq 1$, so $\sqrt[n]{n!} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}= e^{1/n\cdot \ln n!}. $$
Using Stirling's approximation,  we have $\ln n!\sim n\ln n-n,$  and  so the limit of the exponent is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n\ln n-n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n-1=\infty,$ and so the limit is infinite.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Assume that the sequence is bounded by a constant $M$. WLOG, let $M$ be an integer, then we have
$$M^n > n!$$
is true for all $n$. However this is clearly false, since the LHS increases only by $M$ for each increment in $n$ while the $RHS$ increases by $n$, which can get arbitrarily large. Formally, let $c = \frac{M^M}{M!}$ and $k = \lceil \log_{(M+1)/M}c\rceil$. Then
$$(M+k)!>M!(M+1)^k>M!M^k\left(\frac{M+1}{M}\right)^k>\frac{M^{M+k}}{c}c=M^{M+k}$$
Hence the assumption leads to contradiction for $n = M+k$. Q.E.D

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
