# What value does $\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}$ tend to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find where this sequence tends to:
$$\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}$$

My answer is $2$, by using a trick for the $n^{th}$ root: I take the inside and find where $\dfrac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}$ goes, and this is where the original sequence goes.

Comment: Which part of the expression is under the root? And which part is in the denominator?

Comment: all of it after the root times the 1/n

Comment: Please use the following code: `\frac{numerator}{denominator}` and `\sqrt[n]{expression}`

Comment: I’ve edited it. Use braces for roots, exponents, subscripts, etc. Also, using fractions is better.

Comment: As the $n$-th root is clearly $>n$, there's no way the sequence can tend to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [**ratio root criterion**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335500/505767) we have

$$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}{n^n} \quad b_n=\frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}=\sqrt[n] a_n$$

then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n+2)}{n(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\to \frac 4 e$$

which implies that $b_n \to \frac 4 e$.

Comment: Gimusi.Very nice!

Comment: Thanks my dear friend! :)

Answer (score 4):

$$ a_n 
= \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (2n)} 
= \sqrt[n]{1(1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n})\cdots (1+\frac{n}{n})}.
$$ 
$$
\log a_n
= \frac{1}{n} \{ \log 1 + \log (1+\frac{1}{n}) + \log (1+\frac{2}{n}) 
+ \cdots + \log (1+\frac{n}{n}) \}.
$$

We know the above equations. Hence,

$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log a_n = \int_1^2 \log x dx
= [x\log x -x ]_1^2 = 2\log 2 - 1 = \log \frac{4}{e}.
$$

Thus, the limit of $a_n$ is $\frac{4}{e}$.

Comment: Are you using Riemann sum?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, $\log x$ is continuous, and so Riemann integrable.

Comment: Maybe you could explicitly refer to it to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

By Stirling's formula,
\begin{align}
\ln\left[(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)\right]
&=\ln (2n)!-\ln n!=(2n+1/2)\ln(2n)-(n+1/2)\ln n-n+o(1)\\
&=(2n+1/2)\ln 2+n\ln n-n+o(1)
\end{align}
and so
$$\ln\left[n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)\right]
=(2n+1/2)\ln 2+(n+1)\ln n-n+o(1).$$
Then
$$\ln\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}=2\ln 2+\ln n-1+o(1)$$
and
$$\ln\frac{\sqrt[n]{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}}n=2\ln 2-1+o(1).$$
We conclude that your sequence converges to $4/e$.