# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{10n!}{n!^{10}}}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{10n!}{n!^{10}}}$$

So we can solve $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{10(n+1)}{(n+1)^{10}}=0$$

Which is incorrect, where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You can't use the ratio test since it's only used to test convergence or divergence.

Comment: The limit is, in fact, 0: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_(n-%3Einf)((10n!)%2F(n!)%5E10)%5E(1%2Fn))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{10(n+1)!}{(n+1)!^{10}}\frac{n!^{10}}{10n!}=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^{10}}\to 0$$

then using "[**ratio-root**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335500/505767)" criterion

$$\sqrt[n] {a_n} \to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

More generally,
to get
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{(an)!}{n!^{a}}}
$,
use the lazy person's "stirling" approximation
$\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\to \dfrac1{e}
$.

Then,
noting that the "$a$" multiplies $n$
before taking the factorial,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{(an)!}{n!^{a}}}
&=\dfrac{(an)!^{1/n}}{n!^{a/n}}\\
&=\dfrac{((an)!^{1/(an)})^{a}}{(n!^{1/n})^a}\\
&\to\dfrac{(an/e)^{a}}{(n/e)^a}\\
&\to a^a\\
\end{array}
$

When $a=10$ the result is
$10^{10}$.

Note that the
denominator inside the root is
$(10n)!$, not
$10(n!)$.
In that case,
the limit is zero.